# Azure blob trigger function,not working and complains that the contaner/blob format is not correct?

Tags: .net, azure, google-api, youtube-api, azure-functions

I am creating a Azure Blob triggered function, which contains the code to upload a video to YouTube channel whenever there is a video file in the "video" container. The code I am using is from the YouTube API sample code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert . I have taken this code, and I put it inside an Azure function(code below). When I compile and run the function locally, it just says "job has started"(console output below) . Next, I tried to publish this function to the Azure portal and I uploaded a test.mp4 video in my "video" container. When I clicked on 'Run' button of my function in Azure portal, it throws an error such as this, and my video isn't getting uploaded to my YouTube Channel. 
[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/errorinazureportal.jpg) [![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTVi5.png)

Here is snapshot of my storage account named, uploadvideotoyoutube, that has a 'video' container. Inside the 'video' Container I had uploaded a test.mp4 file. 
[image]
Here is my code and other files:

Function1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace YoutubeUploadFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
            var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");
            await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Local.Setting.Json:

```
    {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=uploadvideotoyoutube;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

client_secrets.json:
{

```
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "147300761218-dl0rhktkoj8arh0ebu5pu56es06hje5p.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "mytestproj",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"]
  }
}
```

When I compile and run the function locally, this is the output I see in console:

```
                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2245 Commit hash: 1d094e2f3ef79b9a478a1621ea7ec3f93ac1910d)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13139.0
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: 'a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\UploadVideo\YoutubeUploadFunction\YoutubeUploadFunction\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\host.json'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Host configuration file read:
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "version": "2.0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Reading functions metadata
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] 1 functions found
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Loading startup extension 'AzureStorage'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Loaded extension 'AzureStorage' (3.0.4.0)
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Initializing Host. OperationId: 'a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90'.
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] LoggerFilterOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "MinLevel": "None",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "Rules": [
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     },
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": "None",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": null
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     },
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   ]
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "IsEnabled": true
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] SingletonOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] QueuesOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "BatchSize": 16,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "NewBatchThreshold": 8,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] BlobsOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "CentralizedPoisonQueue": false
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] HttpOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Starting JobHost
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Starting Host (HostId=desktopgq271u4-950774370, InstanceId=16bc66b5-e751-4c00-b383-6f705e303c13, Version=3.0.13139.0, ProcessId=5656, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Loading functions metadata
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] 1 functions loaded
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Found the following functions:
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] YoutubeUploadFunction.Function1.Run
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Initializing function HTTP routes
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] No HTTP routes mapped
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM]
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Host initialized (2033ms)
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Host started (2485ms)
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\UploadVideo\YoutubeUploadFunction\YoutubeUploadFunction\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[3/16/2020 6:02:19 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A74A8599'.

C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.4.1\cli_x64\func.exe (process 5656) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

How can I get the function to run so that it can upload video to my YouTube channel? Does my function need to be changed? Thank you.

Comment: When you run the function locally, did you ever see your function  triggered by blob?

Comment: @GeorgeChen I used Azure Storage Explorer, and I uploded a sample video to my container and it seems to trigger because I see this: 
2020-03-17T01:48:16.534 [Information] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='New blob detected: video/test.mp4', Id=cf36ef6e-1274-4be4-a5ba-86acc1dc937c)

But, how come it is not uploading the test.mp4 to my Youtube channel?

Comment: @GeorgeChen could you also please have a look at my Azure function code and see if something is missing or if it can be improved?

Comment: Suppose your code no problem, even there is something wrong, it should be trigger with exception. So try restart your function then upload a file to blob container, check if your function could be triggered.

Comment: And you don't need to run it manually, if click run I will get your same result, cause no blob is processed.

Comment: @GeorgeChen So on my Azure portal should I upload a new video to my 'Video' container and then click 'Run'?

Comment: Don't click `Run`, wait and check the log if the function is triggered.

Comment: @GeorgeChen where do I go to check the log? I am not sure where the log is located. Are you asking me to do this in Azure Portal or my Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Just check the log like your first screenshot.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Are you asking me to do this in Azure Portal or my Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Any difference? You could choose by yourself.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I don't understand what you said.

Comment: You could upload blob with portal or storage explorer, then check if your function work? Which part confuses you?

Comment: @GeorgeChen I uploaded another video(testagain.mp4) into my video container and this what I see in the logs:

Comment: 020-03-17T02:26:50  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds). 
2020-03-17T02:27:50  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2020-03-17T02:28:50  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2020-03-17T02:29:34.507 [Information] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='New blob detected: video/testagain.mp4', Id=8b573261-aa31-456e-9f02-f3e409233f9f)
2020-03-17T02:30:50  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).

Comment: So your function could work, now if it could process the video like you want(upload to youtube)?

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yes it is not getting uploaded to my YouTube channel. Could you please help?

Comment: When you test locally, could it upload?

Comment: @GeorgeChen no it is not getting uploaded.

Comment: So the problem is your upload video part, looks like it has nothing to do with Function.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yes, could you please help me fix that?

Comment: I have not used the youtube api.

Comment: @GeorgeChen could you try and see what might be the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Which file do you expect the function to upload if you click "run"?

By design, the blob trigger is automatically triggered whenever a new blob is uploaded to the blob account.

You need to upload a file to blob storage while the function is running.

Here is a full example (without Youtube): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

Comment: I expected the function to upload my test.mp4 file to my YouTube channel, which was located inside of 'video' container of my uplodvideotoyoutube storage account(I have included a snapshot of it above).

Comment: Yes, I did upload a test.mp4 file to my blob storage ''video" container. But I don't see the video being uploaded to my YouTube channel.

Comment: Did you start your Azure Function before uploading the file?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Also, does my Azure  function code look fine to you? Or do you think something is missing?

Comment: do you suggest that I first click "Run" button on Function then upload a file into my video container?